# Автозапуск Windows Server 2012 в AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server, windows-server-2012

Есть Windows Server 2012 на AWS. Как я могу автоматизировать его запуск и выключение? Т.е. чтобы сервер автоматически запускался в определенное время и выключался в определенное время.

Comment: Непонятно. Что вы подразумеваете под "выключением"? Ведь ваш сервер находится в облаке, он не может выключиться _физически_. Может, вам нужно какой-то _сервис_ стартовать/останавливать?

Comment: На aws есть возможность останавливать сам инстанс (в данном случае windows server 2012).

Comment: Instance EC2? Это не инстанс Виндовс-Сервера, это именно инстанс EC2. А что крутится внутри него - не важно. Используйте [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/)